# Mac Os / Activating tensorflow virtual environment error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv

After installing tensorflow==0.9.0, 
I want to activate tensorflow virtual environment (tensorflow)$

### In terminal, I want to activate below code finally.

`$ source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate`
I expected:  `(tensorflow)$`

---

But, still have some errors.

---

```
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade virtualenv
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/tensorflow
$ source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
-bash: /Users/user/tensorflow/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

How to solve this "No such file or directory" problem???? I don't know why.

Comment: `ls -lAF ~/tensorflow` ?

Comment: I named virtual environment 'tensorflow'

Comment: I installed 'Anaconda' and new virtualenv 'tensorflow', than it worked successfully.